# Are there 130 Research papers supporting Vaccine/Autism Causation?

Tags: medical-science, vaccines, autism

According to [this compilation](https://www.scribd.com/doc/220807175/130-Research-Papers-Supporting-the-Vaccine-Autism-Link) by Ginger Taylor, MS, there are 130 research papers supporting vaccine/autism causation.

Do all (or at least most) of these papers support the conclusion that one or more vaccines are causal in autism?

Comment: Many of the links seem questionable at best (not actually papers, biased or dubious sources, papers that aren't actually about autism or vaccines, etc), but nobody here is going to look through all 130. I agree that the question linked by @til_b is a duplicate.

Comment: A key bit of terminology here is the difference between "Research paper" and "article."  There very well could be that many, but "Research paper" can mean anything.  I can write a paper right now about that theory, and, having looked at wikipedia, I have done research.  In the cases I looked at on that doc, the papers were not peer reviewed (i.e. had results certified by other scientists), meaning that they exist, but that doesn't mean scientists take them seriously.

Comment: @rougon there are actually peer reviewed articles in that list, but they do not show a link between autism and vaccines. The list introduction probably tries to justify their inclusion by talking vaguely about "underlying medical conditions" of autism as well as vaccines and "their ingredients" (but the inclusion of many of the articles still seems far fetched).

Comment: Apparently someone already did the work of evaluating an older version of the list at http://lizditz.typepad.com/i_speak_of_dreams/2013/08/-those-lists-of-papers-that-claim-vaccines-cause-autism-part-1.html -- it's not really the kind of thing that could be posted in an answer.  It's not notable enough itself, and I'm not sure that it's practical to quote its list of citations.